# Load on bottom of div is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, bind

So this question is not necessarily how to get it to work, because it does. But it is very very buggy. The problem I'm having is that when you scroll down, it sometimes takes a while to load so that the function reactivates or something. Either way the variable is reset and it loads like 5 pages in a row. So it's buggy. I have the code here:

```
var ldid = 10;
jQuery(
    function ($) {
        $('#allpostcontainer').bind('scroll', function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() +
                $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {

                $("#allpostcontainer").append($("<div>").load("/streampage.php?id=" + ldid, function () {
                    ldid = ldid + 10;
                }));

            }
        })
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flag.

If it is loading you can set it to true.

If loading finished you set it back to false
and you make ajax request only if it is false.

```
var ldid = 10,
    isPageLoading = false;

jQuery(
    function ($) {
        $('#allpostcontainer').bind('scroll', function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() +
                $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight && !isPageLoading) {

                isPageLoading = true;

                $("#allpostcontainer").append($("<div>").load("/streampage.php?id=" + ldid, function () {
                ldid = ldid + 10;

                isPageLoading = false;

            }));

        }
    })
}
);
```

Comment: Still not working. Tried adding "console.log(ldid)" in the function and I get some pretty weird results `20
30 
20
40 
30
20`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set your Div tag at the end of the "allpostcontainer" div then put below script in your page.

(#bottom is Div tag id which you need to display at the bottom. #allpostcontainer is div tag id which is main Div with scroll)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#bottom').css('position', 'absolute');
        $('#bottom').css('top', $('#allpostcontainer').height() - $('#bottom').height());
    });
</script>
```

Please let me know if you have any query.

Thank you...